# Como faço pra ter a soma dos valores que adiciono a lista?

Tags: javascript, variáveis, matemática

Fiz esse programa pra listar itens de um orçamento.
Ele adiciona, da uma breve descrição do que foi adicionado e mostra o valor do item.

Eu quero somar todos os valores e mostrar um total que atualiza a cada item listado, só que não faço ideia de como fazer.

Se eu peço pra calcular fora da função da erro, e se coloco dentro o valor do total atualiza igual o valor do ultimo item listado...

<sub>Nunca tinha usado StackOverflow, se puderem também dar feedbacks de maneiras de estruturar essa pergunta pra que o tópico não seja fechado novamente eu agradeço!</sub>

```js
function listar() {
  let getn1 = document.getElementById('n1').value
  let getn2 = document.getElementById('n2').value
  let getn3 = document.getElementById('n3').value
  let list = document.getElementById('list')
  let m3 = getn1 * getn2 * getn3
  var resultado = m3 * 10
  let valor = resultado.toLocaleString('pt-br', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'BRL'
  })


  list.innerHTML += `<li>Serviço de recorte de ${getn1}m X ${getn2}m e profundidade de ${getn3}m.............................${valor}</li>`

  document.getElementById('n1').value = ''
  document.getElementById('n2').value = ''
  document.getElementById('n3').value = ''

  total()

  function total() {
    let result = document.getElementById('res')
    var res = 0
    var final = res + resultado
    result.innerHTML = `Total: ..........................${final}`

  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3>Serviço de Recorte CNC</h3>
  <input type="number" id="n1" placeholder="Altura">
  <input type="number" id="n2" placeholder="Largura">
  <input type="number" id="n3" placeholder="Profundidade">
  <input type="button" id="add" value="Adicionar" onclick="listar()">
  <ol id="list">
  </ol>
  <p id="res">Resultado:.................</p>
</body>
```

Comment: nunca usei o stack, vou editar aqui....

Comment: Nessa parte ele só ta descrevendo, não entra no cálculo, de qualquer forma vou editar denovo, eu quero é a soma dos resultados listados

Answer (score 1):

Sua função aninhada `total()` não está totalizando, toda vez que é chamada o valor da variável `res` é iniciado em zero.

```
function total() {
    let result = document.getElementById('res')
    //Aqui res é iniciado em 0.
    var res = 0              
    var final = res + resultado
    result.innerHTML = `Total: ..........................${final}`
}
```

A uma saída imediata seria remover a declaração `var res = 0` de dentro do código e a passar a variável `final` para o escopo global. A função `total()` pode ser transformada numa expressão [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) que é uma função em JavaScript que é executada assim que definida.

```js
var final = 0

function listar() {
  let getn1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
  let getn2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
  let getn3 = document.getElementById('n3').value;
  let list = document.getElementById('list');
  let m3 = getn1 * getn2 * getn3;
  var resultado = m3 * 10;
  let valor = resultado.toLocaleString('pt-br', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'BRL'
  });


  list.innerHTML += `<li>Serviço de recorte de ${getn1}m X ${getn2}m e profundidade de ${getn3}m.............................${valor}</li>`;

  document.getElementById('n1').value = '';
  document.getElementById('n2').value = '';
  document.getElementById('n3').value = '';

  //A função total foi convertida em um IIFE.
  (function() {
    let result = document.getElementById('res')
    final += resultado
    result.innerHTML = `Total: ..........................${final}`
  })()

}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3>Serviço de Recorte CNC</h3>
  <input type="number" id="n1" placeholder="Altura">
  <input type="number" id="n2" placeholder="Largura">
  <input type="number" id="n3" placeholder="Profundidade">
  <input type="button" id="add" value="Adicionar" onclick="listar()">
  <ol id="list">
  </ol>
  <p id="res">Resultado:.................</p>
</body>
```

Ou então remover de uma vez a função `total()`.

```js
let final = 0;

function listar() {
  let getn1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
  let getn2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
  let getn3 = document.getElementById('n3').value;
  let list = document.getElementById('list');
  let m3 = getn1 * getn2 * getn3;
  var resultado = m3 * 10;
  let valor = resultado.toLocaleString('pt-br', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'BRL'
  });


  list.innerHTML += `<li>Serviço de recorte de ${getn1}m X ${getn2}m e profundidade de ${getn3}m.............................${valor}</li>`;

  document.getElementById('n1').value = '';
  document.getElementById('n2').value = '';
  document.getElementById('n3').value = '';

  let result = document.getElementById('res');
  final += resultado;
  result.innerHTML = `Total: ..........................${final}`;

}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3>Serviço de Recorte CNC</h3>
  <input type="number" id="n1" placeholder="Altura">
  <input type="number" id="n2" placeholder="Largura">
  <input type="number" id="n3" placeholder="Profundidade">
  <input type="button" id="add" value="Adicionar" onclick="listar()">
  <ol id="list">
  </ol>
  <p id="res">Resultado:.................</p>
</body>
```